# What is the best Approach for Banner management(Slider)?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-server, visual-web-part

Im about to develop a webpart for banner (Slider) management,
which is reading images from Image library and shows it in the webpart.

I'm using Jquery to do this. What is the best way to pass the images to user control that I have in my library?

Note:**I dont want to write write any HTML tags by c#.**

Comment: Why don't you use Repeater control, you will not need to write HTML tags in C# instead the user control designer file

Answer (score 0):

there is a simple way to do that. You can simply implement it as slider instead of developing one.

```
1.Download the SlidesJS plugin files and extract them to your computer.
2.Create a Picture Library called “Slides” and add the plugin’s slide images to it.
3.Make sure your search has crawled your newly added content (in most cases, waiting 5-10 minutes will do the job)
4.Add a Search Results Web Part to a page.
5.Configure the Search Results Web Part search query to return slide images from your Picture Library.
6.Upload the SlidesJS plugin files to the Style Library.
Upload the display template files to “Master Page Gallery -> Display Templates -> Search”.
7.Configure the Search Results Web Part control and item display templates.
```

for more info you can have a look http://en.share-gate.com/blog/image-slider-with-sharepoint-2013-search-results

Comment: im not clear about search result web part thing,i want to use only webpart without depending other web parts.